# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 3057 : invalid start byte error while importing some python libraries

Tags: utf-8, encode, python-3.8

While importing some packages in python using the 'from' command,
eg: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
I am facing an error : 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c in position 3057: invalid start byte.
Can anyone please me understand where I am getting wrong..!

Answer (score -2):

please add other details like logs or the screenshot

This might cause by decoding issue.
try adding:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
```

to the top of the code.
Maybe your default decoding for Python files is ANSI or else.

Comment: This is  a comment, not an answer.  Also the `coding` comment declares the encoding of the *source file only* and UTF-8 is the default for Python 3 anyway.  It doesn't affect other encode/decode operations.